# It is possible to import urlset in segment with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am wondering if I can create a segment by importing a urlset (CVS, Excel, ...). Currently, for each page I want to add to the segment I have to manually add the specific page as shown in the picture.

This is ok for small set of pages but I'd like to ask if a short procedure exists to accomplish this task.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the API would be one way of simplifying this task.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments

If you use R: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/r-google-analytics